# Replace packaged install with one from source

Tags: apt, software-installation

Ubuntu currently only has a package for OpenIPMI 2.0.18 - I need OpenIPMI 2.0.19 or later.

How should I go about replacing the Ubuntu package with one from the OpenIPMI source itself?

I am planning on:

```
apt-get remove OpenIPMI
```

and then for the latest OpenIPMI

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: Typically, we have to use sudo for the install command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you miss out on a lot. Short of doing a proper package, this is what I'd do. I'm assuming you have build-essential, but the rest should be handled.

remove the old package with `apt-get remove OpenIPMI`

clean out the old dependancies with `apt-get autoremove` (I suppose this is optional, but it ensures that the next step works perfectly)

run `apt-get install -s OpenIPMI` and note down what it depends on.

Install these dependancies

`sudo apt-get build-dep OpenIPMI` to install the *build* dependancies (as distinct from dependancies that provide shared libs and other necessary things you don't actually want to compile yourself) - in theory you can work these out from your config file erroring out, but I have no idea why anyone would do that.

THEN

```
./configure
make
make install
```

This should handle most of the things you need painlessly. In your shoes I'd use the excellent `checkinstall` to make a quick and dirty package over make install, just so you can remove your own build cleanly with dpkg (and if you can be bothered, set dependancies correctly there should you want to use this on more than one system).

Comment: Normally, there's no need to uninstall the `apt-get` version because the compiled version almost always installs to `/usr/local/bin` so it has priority on your PATH. To verify this, run `which <commandname>` after installation and it will show the command under `/usr/local/bin` instead of the version under `/usr/bin`. Also, we need to use `sudo make install` to give permission to install to `/usr/local/bin` and to uninstall, just run `sudo make uninstall` from the build directory.

Comment: The reason the compiled version installs to `/usr/local/bin` is so that you can have both versions installed. This way, installing the compiled version will not break any dependencies for packages that depend on this package because you don't have to remove the `apt-get` version.