# Replacing an APT-version of a package with source code version?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, software-installation, software-sources, clang

How can I replace a package installed via APT(or any other package managers) with the version from source without violating system? My problem is the same as this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401954/replace-packaged-install-with-one-from-source), but I think the answer is not really helpful.

For example, I am trying to build a project that requires Clang (version 12.0.0+), but the latest version of Clang (APT) is 10.0.0, so apparently I have to install Clang from source (GitHub). So I have 3 questions:

- Should I need to remove the old Clang(APT)? 
  When I tried `sudo apt remove clang`, the system also asked me to remove a lot of dependencies **(REALLY IMPORTANT)**, and I think the system would corrupt if I remove Clang.
- How can I set up the **`PATH`** so that the system will use the later version of Clang, because there are two versions of it in my laptop?
- If a package is install via APT, it is very easy to update it via `sudo apt upgrade`. but how can I upgrade a package via git without reinstall it again? Every clang update takes me almost half a day to complete.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that you cannot remove clang because of dependencies. The path for the compiled version should already be set to /usr/local/bin by default and the system will automatically use this version. See the answer by Ray for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, to answer your 3 questions,

1. No, you don't need to remove the apt-installed `clang`.  Just keep it where it is in `/usr/bin/clang`.

   If you download and install `clang` as a user, you probably have the option to put it in your home directory.  If it's installed in a system-level directory, it would probably go under `/usr/local/`.  For example, `/usr/local/bin/`.  So, the two versions can co-exist.
2. The `$PATH` variable is the easiest part.  First, type `env | grep PATH` and see if your `PATH` variable has already been set for you.  What you want to see is the order in which the paths appear.  Earlier in the list is higher priority.  It's possible that `/usr/local/bin/` has already been set for you.  If not, then you can set it in your `~/.bashrc` file.  Do something like:

   `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:"$PATH"`

   somewhere in the file.  Of course, if you reversed the above:

   `export PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/bin/`

   then you've placed `/usr/local/bin/` lowest in priority.  You don't want that.  Other parts of the file might put things before `/usr/local/bin/`.  That's ok as long as it remains before `/usr/bin/`.

   Then type `source ~/.bashrc` and try `env | grep PATH` to see if you've done it correctly.  Note that this will affect not just `clang` but all your programs so if you had other programs in `/usr/local/bin/` previously, then they will now have a higher priority over `/usr/bin/`.
3. Your last point is the hardest part as there is no easy way.  What you get from GitHub is usually the source code.  If there are pre-built binaries, then great.

   But most likely, it's the source code and you will have to (a) compile and (b) install every time you want to update.  I haven't installed `clang` manually before, but for some programs with a `Makefile`, one would do a `make; make install`.  The first command compiles and the second installs it.  Prior to this, one might set the directory to install to using `./config`, `cmake`, etc.

My personal opinion is if you don't need the latest feature, then you rarely need to keep a compiler *that* up to date.  So I don't think you need to re-compile `clang` that often...  If you're developing a program for distribution, then rarely will the users also have such a new compiler.

Does this help?

Comment: Usually, we have to do `make; sudo make install`. Don't forget the `sudo` on the install command or it won't have permission to install to `/usr/local/bin` which is typically the default directory.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: @mchid Thanks for the clarification!  Though, one can install into one's home directory as well.  In that case, `sudo` isn't necessary.  Depends what the OP chooses.

Comment: I prefer to use checkinstall (it creates a deb file) for that, so I can remove the build with apt.